# textarea and vertical alignment inside a table

Tags: html, css, textarea, vertical-alignment

We have a table with two columns: in each row there is a label on the left and an input box on the right.
We use `vertical-align=text-bottom;` to align the bottom of the label text with the bottom of the text in the input boxes.

So far so good.

However, sometimes we have a textarea (multiple lines) instead of the input box. The bottom of the label on the left is aligned with the bottom of the **last** line of the textarea.

Is there a way to align the text on the left with the **first** row of the textarea?

A simplified example

```
<table class="waiFormTable">
  <tr>
    <td><label>Label 1:</label></td>
    <td><input id="id" type="text" name="name" value="value" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Label 2:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="id" type="text" name="name" value="value" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in the CSS we define:

```
table.waiFormTable thead tr,
table.waiFormTable tbody tr {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

In this example I would like to have "Label 1:" text-bottom aligned with the first row of the textarea.

Comment: Can you start a jsfiddle and are you open to a javascript solution?

Comment: A comment on the down-vote is always appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, when you have a textarea, you want to align to the top.

Apply a special style (example : `labelTextarea`) in this case

```
<tr>
    <td class="labelTextarea"><label >Label 2:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="id1" type="text" name="name1"  >value</textarea></td>
</tr>
```

with:

```
.labelTextarea{
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but then the top of the text of the label is aligned with the upper line of the textarea. The top of the text in the textarea does not correspond to the top of the textarea itself. I know is not a major difference but it looks "wrong".

Comment: Ok, so keep this solution and leave the padding top and bottom of the inputs like `input, textarea{  padding-bottom: 0;    padding-top: 0;}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

1. add a class to the `td` enclosing the `textarea`
2. set the same `font` and `px` for the `table`, `input` and `textarea`.
3. set a `vertical-align:top;` and some `padding` on the `td` enclosing the `textarea`

   ```
   table.waiFormTable, table.waiFormTable input, table.waiFormTable textarea{
       font-family:arial;
       font-size:12px;
   }

   table.waiFormTable thead tr, table.waiFormTable tbody tr {
         vertical-align: text-bottom;
   }

   .textarea{
       vertical-align:top;
       padding-top:2px;
   }
   ```

Note: you may need to adjust by a pixel or two.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ccew8/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of using: `vertical-align=text-bottom;`

you could use: `margin-top= 4px;`

or some other amount of pixels that should line up all of the labels with the bottom of the first line.

Comment: I thought about that but generally I don't like using absolute values to define the formatting. Depending on the font/browser/OS the page could be rendered differently.

Comment: I agree but I don't think there is any other way to do this as the text area doesn't have a first row value. I think you should test this out in multiple browsers and define the font yourself. In fact if you set the cells' and input boxes' heights yourself then it should look the same no matter what the browser/OS.